# Views Data export xml

Tags: views

Drupal 10.2.4 php - 8.2.16

I have created a Views Data export xml but the link to the xml file only works when I am logged in. When I'm not logged in the link works, but the xml file is empty. How can I have this link so that non-registered users can also see it. I tried with the xls that is downloaded, but if I am not logged in, an empty file is downloaded.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do anonymous users have access to the nodes that are the contents of the view?

Comment: Can you post to view's yaml?